# Independent sum in C++ function

Tags: c++

I want my program to compute a sum of values in nodes which are at distance = n from the root of a RB-tree. I have a recursive function which finds such nodes but I have no idea how to sum all of them. How it looks:

```
void nSum (RBTreeNode* B, int n) {
    if (B == NULL || n < 0)
        return;
    if (n == 0) {
        Integer* v = (Integer*) B->value;
        S += v->number // there I want to make an independent sum of them
        return;
    }
    nSum (B->right, n-1);
    nSum (B->left, n-1);
}
```

Im pretty new to this and I havent found any answer.

Tried the following:

```
    void nSum (RBTreeNode* B, int n, vector <int> sum) {
    if (B == NULL || n < 0)
        return;
    if (n == 0) {
        int* v = (int*) B->value;
        sum.push_back(v->number);
        return;
    }
    nSum (B->right, n-1, sum);
    nSum (B->left, n-1, sum);
}
```

But then the sum is empty

Comment: Why use a vector and not just int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a function like this:

```
void nSum (RBTreeNode* B, int n, vector <int> sum)
```

The vector that the function gets is a copy of the vector that you pass in. So if nSum modifies the vector, that has no effect on the vector in the code that called nSum. This is called passing by value.

You can also pass by reference, which would give nSum access to the same vector that is passed in, and any modification made in nSum will be affect the vector in the calling code. The way you pass by reference is like this:

```
void nSum (RBTreeNode* B, int n, vector <int>& sum)
```

Notice the "&". But the vector is not necessary, you only need to keep track of the sum. You could do this instead:

```
void nSum (RBTreeNode* B, int n, int& sum)
```

Now every time nSum is called it can modify the sum int, and it will effect the value outside the function.

Comment: Now it is correct, need to work on theory. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This sum can be expressed in a simple recursive formula (as do many things the pertain to the structure of binary trees):

```
S(root, 0) = root->value;
S(root, n) = S(root->left_child, n - 1) + S(root->right_child, n - 1);
```

You may notice from the formula, that it's not enough to just invoke the recursive function twice. You need to actually sum the results. Which means the function must return something that can even be summed:

```
int nSum (RBTreeNode* B, int n) {
   // Take a stab at completing it yourself

   return nSum(B->left, n-1) + nSum(B->right, n-1);
}
```